# Regex get sentence with specific word

Tags: java, regex

I have a lot of text which looks like that (this is example):

> some random strings, content etc, nothing special OPENING BY XZXDS first text i want to get. another random strings, some unnecessary news etc CLOSING second text i want to get. and then some more content and content OPENING BY LLXAS third text i want to get. again boring news, nothing CLOSING fourth text i want to get. and so on...

I want to get every sentence that contains word : TEXT . for example, in this case I would get:

> first text i want to get.
>
> second text i want to get.
>
> third text i want to get.
>
> fourth text i want to get.

The way I think it is possible is:
In my text there is random text, but this text always end "OPENING BY XXXX" or "CLOSING" . So I think that I could get my text which is between word "OPENING BY XXXX" or "CLOSING" and "." (dots). XXX can be different, it needs to be exclude. Can somene help with regex function for this?

Just exlcude everything what is before OPENING BY, exclude one word what is after OPENING BY, get my text till it reaches "."

I used to have something similar, but It was easier because I got sentence with specific word between two dots. I don't have two dots between my sentence now.
I'm adding code for what I used to have:

```
String pattern = "[^\.]*\bSPECIFICWORD\b[^\.]*"
```

I think we can keep second part of this, but first part needs to be modificated.

I need it for my Java app.
Thank you for help.

Comment: Improve your sample text please, as it does not include the 'OPENING BY' and 'CLOSING' text.

Comment: @Bruno I improved it a little bit, hopefully you'll understand what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:(?:opening by [^ ]+)|(?:closing))"
            + "((?:[^\\.]*? )*TEXT(?:[^\\.]*?))\\."
            , Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    final String text = "random text random text random text opening "
            + "by xysd FIRST TEXT I WANT TO GET. random text random "
            + "text random text closing SECOND TEXT I WANT TO GET. "
            + "random text random text random text opening by lxcvznk "
            + "THIRD TEXT. random text random text random text random "
            + "text closing FOURTH TEXT...etc";
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    while(m.find())
    {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

Output:

```
 FIRST TEXT I WANT TO GET
 SECOND TEXT I WANT TO GET
 THIRD TEXT
 FOURTH TEXT
```

`(?:opening by [^ ]+)|(?:closing))` starts with "opening by xxx" or "closing"

`(?:[^\\.]*? )*` any non-dot characters followed by space (depending on your needs space can be excluded) zero or more times

`(?:[^\\.]*?))\\.` non-dot sequence followed by .

If text input is exceptionally large, single regex may be not the best approach, it may be faster to search for prefix then to dot character explicitly.

As discussed in comments, if you want to capture sentences containing any one of two words, say, ONE or ANOTHER, just replace TEXT with `(?:ONE|ANOTHER)`. It is described in [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) docs in Logical operators section.

If you want to know which one exactly did you catch, you can use capturing group `(ONE|ANOTHER)` and get it in `matcher.group(2)`:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:(?:opening by [^ ]+)|(?:closing))"
            + "((?:[^\\.]*? )*(ONE|ANOTHER)(?:[^\\.]*?))\\."
            , Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    final String text = "random text random text random text opening "
            + "by xysd FIRST ONE I WANT TO GET. random text random "
            + "text random text closing SECOND ANOTHER I WANT TO GET. "
            + "random text random text random text opening by lxcvznk "
            + "ANOTHER TEXT. random text random text random text random "
            + "text closing FOURTH ONE...etc";
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    while(m.find())
    {
        System.out.println(m.group(1) + "<-" + m.group(2));
    }

FIRST ONE I WANT TO GET<-ONE
SECOND ANOTHER I WANT TO GET<-ANOTHER
ANOTHER TEXT<-ANOTHER
FOURTH ONE<-ONE
```

Comment: text input is large, it is from html document, and the text I want to get is on the bottom of this document. I'll try the function you wrote for me and we'll see.

Comment: By large I mean processing hundreds thousands of megabyte files, for single html probably would be negligible on modern hardware.

Comment: Ok, I checked and it works fine! Thank you. One more question. I have a button, and after click I want to go to next sentence. Do I have to put all matches to array or is it simpliest way to move between all sentences?

Comment: In general you don't have to pre-calculate all matches, you can keep just Matcher and execute find() on the same instance with the button click (to show button disabled when no next match exists, you can create two matches in advance and then proceed by one). You can apply the same technique to skip by next 10 or alike with another button. However, if you have small number of matches, say 100 or 500 (which is reasonable otherwise UI has no point) it is ok to pre-store in a List and navigate on the list, optimization is not worth the effort. Btw. you can accept the answer if you wish : )

Comment: Ok, I'll accept. Just one more little thing. Can you add to regex expression, that I can look for TEXT or TEXT1. Because sometimes I want to look for sentence which contains TEXT or TEXT1. Thank you. That'd be all I wanted.

Comment: I did expand the answer to contain this case.

Comment: Thank you, it helps me a lot.

Comment: Hey, could you add to this regex expression that the sentence can end as `!`or `?` . I've tried to add it but I don't get it. Thank you.

Comment: Ok I think I get it, correct me if I am wrong. `(?:(?:opening by [^ ]+)|(?:closing))((?:[^\\.?!]*? )*(ONE|ANOTHER)(?:[^\\.]*?))[.?!]`

Comment: Almost, add also to negated set after (ONE|ANOTHER),  so [^\\.] it will not eat ? or !: `(?:(?:opening by [^ ]+)|(?:closing))((?:[^\\.?!]*? )*(ONE|ANOTHER)(?:[^\\.?!]*?))[\\.?!]`